# Generated <a> links to wrong URL

Tags: joomla-4.x, module, development

I generate a link in a module as follows:

```
$user->contactAddress = str_replace("//", "/", trim(JUri::base() . $params->get('defaultContactAddress') . '?' . $params->get('parameterName') . '=' . $user->cfid));
```

where

```
JUri::base() is https://mydomain.tld/devel/j4/
$params->get('defaultContactAddress') is "direktkontakt"
$params->get('parameterName') is "cfid"
$user->cfid is 99
```

The link is properly generated, `echo $user->contactAddress;` gives `https:/mydomain.tld/devel/j4/direktkontakt?cfid=99`.

The following is way unexpected:

```
<a href="<?=$user->contactAddress;?>"><?=$user->contactAddress;?></a>
```

results in

```
<a href="https:/mydomain.tld/devel/j4/direktkontakt?cfid=99">https:/mydomain.tld/devel/j4/direktkontakt?cfid=99</a>
```

BUT all tested browsers (Edge, Firefox, Chrome) point to

```
https://mydomain.tld/mydomain.tld/devel/j4/direktkontakt?cfid=99
```

Has anyone any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `str_replace()` call breaks the URL by changing `https://mydomain.tld` to `https:/mydomain.tld`. The code can be changed in many ways, depending on your use case. You may add validation to `defaultContactAddress` field to prevent users adding a leading slash in the first place. Or you may trim the leading slash from the value and not from the whole URL:

```
ltrim($params->get('defaultContactAddress'), '/')
```

On HTML pages it's generally not necessary to include absolute URLs. So you can use `JUri::base(true)` to get just the path of your Joomla root which would also avoid the issue.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I didn't see the second slash after https was missing.